# Як правильно перекласти технічний текст: "push communications" / "push mechanism"

Tags: переклад, from-english, запозичені-слова

Необхідно перекласти частину технічного тексту і не можу знайти відповідники в українській мові для таких термінів як "push mechanism"/"push communications"

Push — *поштовх (натиск)*, communications — *спілкування*

Спілкування "поштовх" аж ніяк не звучить, штовхальне спілкування теж(

Знайшла варіанти, коли використовують "дослівний" переклад:
push method — *метод "поштовх"*
[Переклад "push communication" на російську](http://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/push+communication)

Comment: Вітаємо на сайті stackexchange. 1. Це не сайт для перекладів, хоч тут за певних умов і можна питати про переклад. 2. Навіть якщо ви не можете знайти прямі відповідники, ви маєте спочатку хоча б походити словниками, надати кілька можливих варіантів перекладу цієї фрази і спитати, чи не припустилися ви помилки при перекладі. Тоді можливий розгляд якоїсь відповіді на питання. P.S. Не сприймайте за напад, просто спільнота має певні стандарти для запитань. Мусите їх дотримуватися. Зніму свій мінус, коли побачу, що питання відредаґовано.

Comment: так. мінус зняв, бо ви почали рухатися в правильному напрямку.
тепер спробуйте пошукати окремо переклади обох слів і поскладати з них словосполучення. це вже вважатиметься проведеною самостійною роботою, і решта користувачів зможе долучитися до обговорення, а я може й плюс поставлю.

Comment: Я теж зніму мінус, як і попередній коментатор. Варто ще дописати, чим са́ме вам не подобаються / не підходять самостійно знайдені варіанти: «поштовх-комунікація» і «пуш-комунікація». Мені вони теж не дуже до вподоби, але ваші причини можуть бути зовсім не такі, як мої.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спали на думку два варіанти для *push/pull communication*:

1. штовхай-комунікація
   тягни-комунікація
2. комунікація до клієнта/споживача/покупця/користувача/...
   комунікація до джерела

Виходив з таких визначень:

> **Push communication**
>   Відправлена певним отримувачам, які потребують цю інформацію. Це гарантує, що інформація розподілена, але не гарантує, що вона була отримана і зрозуміла аудиторією. Включає листи, нагадування, звіти, електронні листи, факси, блоги, прес релізи тощо.
>
> **Pull communication**
>   Використовується для дуже великих об'ємів інформації чи дуже великих аудиторій. Вимагає від отримувача доступитись до інформації самостійно. Ці методи включають сайти в локальній мережі, e-навчання, бази даних отриманих уроків, сховища знань тощо.